# null value for mathematic mySQL

Tags: mysql

there is my  code

```
select @k:=if(kode="k",nominal,0) as Kredit,@d:=if(kode="d",nominal,0) as
 debet, @s:=@s+@k-@d as saldo from trx
```

I want to show results in a reduction based on the structure of the table , but the result is the null value

Comment: *As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement.* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

Answer (score 0):

`@s` needs to be set to value as `1 + NULL = NULL` in MySQL; You can left join a select to set variables before the statement is executed if you cannot maintain a MySQL session as below:

```
SELECT 
    @k := IF(kode = "k", nominal, 0) AS Kredit, 
    @d := IF(kode = "d", nominal, 0) as debet, 
    @s:= @s + @k - @d AS saldo 
FROM trx 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT @s := 0) AS `setVar` ON 1=1
```